# Como mandar llamar un procedimiento almacenado en el controlador en ASP.NET MVC y Entity framework

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5, stored-procedure, entity-framework-6, controller

Tengo este código en mi controlador y mis procedimientos almacenados ya están mapeados. Accedo a la base de datos a través de `Entity framework` y está definido el `edmx`. Quisiera saber como es el código para mandar llamar(utilizar) mi procedimiento almacenado para crear un nuevo registro.

```
public class pruebacontroller:controller
 private pruebaxEntities db=new pruebaxEntities();

public Action Result Index()

{

return View(db.spmotrartabla().ToList());//Me muestra la tabla a través de un procedimiento almacenado  y ya cree su vista

}

//Quiero saber que código va en esta parte para mandar llamar el procedimiento almacenado para crear

public Action Result Create()
{
  return View();
}

[httpPost]
public ActionResult Create (FormCollection collection)
try

{
  return RedirectToAction("Index")
}

catch

{
   return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que crear un los ObjectParameter que regresarán los parámetros de salida, los parámetros de entrada deberán estar en el orden como lo definiste en tu Procedimiento Almacenado.

```
ObjectParameter parametroOut1 = new ObjectParameter("NombreParametro", typeof(String));
db.NombredelProcedimiento(valor1,valor2,valor3, parametroOut1);
Console.WriteLine(name.Value);
```

Comment: Disculpa compañero el ObjectParameter va dentro del 
public Action Result Create()? o en lugar de

Comment: Disculpa compañero el ObjectParameter va dentro del 
public Action Result Create()? o en lugar de

Comment: public Action Result Create()
{
 ObjectParameter parametroOut1 = new 
       ObjectParameter("NombreParametro", typeof(String));
 db.NombredelProcedimiento(valor1,valor2,valor3, parametroOut1);
 Console.WriteLine(name.Value);
   return View();
}

Comment: sale error en db.NombredelProcedimiento(valor1,valor2,valor3, parametroOut1 Me dice que los valores no existen en el contexto actual

Comment: 'NombredelProcedimiento' es el nombre que le pusiste a tu procedimiento y valor1, valor2, y valor3 son los parámetros de entrada, vas a definir tus parámetros de entrada según necesite tu procedimiento almacenado

Comment: si lo hice con mis parametros y el nombre de mi procedimiento alamacenado, y en el modelo edmx ya estan los parametros, tambien los escribi tal cual estan en el store